# Accessing pointers like an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Given:

```
int *ip = new int[10];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   ip[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Do the brackets work accordingly to what I want it to do? (Not necessarily creating an array and filling it up with 1, 2, ... 10)

Comment: Yes. It's functionally equivalent to: `*(ip + i) = i + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

`ip[i]` is identical to `*(ip + i)` so yes, it will do what you think it will. Except the creation, which has happened on the first line.